# Django REST Framework: UniqueConstraint on custom User model is not working

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have an application where I want two user types (UserType1 and UserType2). I am using the `AbstractBaseUser` model with boolean flags and then created OneToOne fields on the user type objects back to the user (no extra data added at this point).

I have a unique requirement where I want to enforce a `UniqueConstraint` where there can only be one user type with a given email.

The boolean flags used to determine the user type are `is_user_type_1` and `is_user_type_2` and the models are defined below:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            **kwargs
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_user_type_1 = False
        user.is_user_type_2 = False
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': "A user with that username already exists.",
        },
    )
    email = models.EmailField()
    is_user_type_1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_user_type_2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=[
                    'email',
                    'is_user_type_1',
                    'is_user_type_2',
                ],
                name='unique_email_by_type'
            )
        ]

class UserType1(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        related_name='user_type1',
    )


class UserType2(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        related_name='user_type2'
    )
```

where I'm using a `UniqueConstraint` in the `User.Meta` based on the `email`, `user_type_1`, and `user_type_2` to meet the specific requirement. I tried to follow the Django doc here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/

To add some more context, I also have the following serializers for `UserType1` and `UserType2` where I want to only expose endpoints for the user types and hide the management of the `User` object:

```
from django.db import transaction
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import User, Athlete, Trainer


class AbstractUserTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='user.email')
    password = serializers.CharField(source='user.password', write_only=True)

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')

        user_data['is_user_type_1'] = self._is_user_type_1()
        user_data['is_user_type_2'] = self._is_user_type_2()

        user = User.objects.create(
            **user_data
        )

        user_type = self.Meta.model.objects.create(
            user=user,
            **validated_data
        )

        return user_type

    @transaction.atomic
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user = instance.user

        updated_user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user.email = updated_user_data.get('email', user.email)

        user.save()

        instance.user = user
        instance.save()

        return instance

    def _is_user_type_1(self) -> bool:
        return False

    def _is_user_type_2(self) -> bool:
        return False

    @staticmethod
    def _get_default_fields() -> tuple:
        return (
            'pk',
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'created',
            'modified',
        )

    @staticmethod
    def _get_default_extra_kwargs() -> tuple:
        return {
            'pk': {
                'read_only': True
            }
        }


class UserType1Serializer(AbstractUserTypeSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserType1
        fields = AbstractUserTypeSerializer._get_default_fields()
        extra_kwargs = AbstractUserTypeSerializer._get_default_extra_kwargs()

    def _is_user_type_1(self):
        return True

    def _is_user_type_2(self):
        return False


class UserType2Serializer(AbstractUserTypeSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserType2
        fields = AbstractUserTypeSerializer._get_default_fields()
        extra_kwargs = AbstractUserTypeSerializer._get_default_extra_kwargs()

    def _is_user_type_1(self):
        return False

    def _is_user_type_2(self):
        return True
```

The User model was registered in my settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.User'
```

However, the `UniqueConstraint` is not working and I am still able to create two users where the `email`, `user_type_1`, and `user_type_2` fields are the same. I assume it is something to do with the nested classes above but was unable to find the reason within my tests or online.

Any help for an explanation of why this constraint is not being fulfilled on the object creation would be greatly appreicated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve the problem but I did find a solution if anyone else comes across this. I think the main reason the validation is not running is due to the Nested model. Since we are creating the `User` implicitly through the `UserType1` and `UserType2` objects by calling `create_user` from the `UserManager`, Django is not automatically running the validation on `save`.

To work around this, I explicitly called `validate_unique` in the `create_user` method of the `UserManager` class above like so:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    The manager for the User class
    """
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email, and password
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            **kwargs
        )

        // !!This is what was added!!
        user.validate_unique()

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```